# How can I turn a rare item into a rare magic item?

Tags: path-of-exile

I turned a silk vest into a rare, and then later found that I could not change it into a magic item, because it isn't normal.

Is there a way to turn a rare item into a magic item?

It was normal before I made it rare, so I think that if I had known before hand, I would have been able to make it magic, and then make it rare. I only started playing the game recently, so I have no idea of how things work.

The reason I was trying to turn it into a magic item is because when I used an orb of augmentation on it the message said "failed to apply item: target is not magic", I also tried to use an orb of alteration and it said the same thing.

Comment: There is no such thing as "rare magic item"... **Magic** item is an item with up to two magic bonuses, while **rare** item is one with up to six of the *same* bonuses. Hence, a creating a rare is always better than creating a magic item.

Comment: And about turning a magic item into a rare one: you need other currency items for that than you need to turn a normal in a rare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While [Samyam's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/238785/15890) is full of good information, it doesn't fully answer the question, which is *"can I turn a Rare (yellow) item into a Magic (blue) item?"*.

The answer is yes, but it takes two steps:

1. Use an [Orb of Scouring](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Orb_of_Scouring) on the rare item to remove all properties from the item, turning it into a normal (white) item.
2. Use an [Orb of Transmutation](https://www.poewiki.net/wiki/Orb_of_Transmutation) to upgrade the normal item into a magical (blue) item.

This process will not change the item's quality, sockets, or links.

Answer (score 7):

POE item tiers are pretty simple:

- **Normal Items** - Has 1 or no implicit modifier for the item.
- **Magical Items** - Has 2 additional modifiers for the item.
- **Rare Items** - Has upto 6 modifiers for the item.

You can use the following Orbs for modifying item rarity -

- Normal - Magical : *Orb of Transmutation*.
- Magical +1 Affix : *Orb of
  Augmentation*.
- Magical Reroll: *Orb of Alteration*
- Normal - Rare : *Orb of Alchemy*
- Magical - Rare: *Regal Orb* (Adds only 1 affix and leaves
  other affix slots open. Used in crafting)
- Rare Reroll: *Chaos Orb*
- Rare +1 Affix: *Exalted Orb*

You can read more here - http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Magic#Items

Comment: You're wrong. Normal item does not necessary have an implicit mod. http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Implicit_modifier . Also, it would be right to call 'modifiers' affixes. Regal orb statement is incorrect too: after regaling an item will have either 3 or 4 slots open, depending on how many were used before regaling. Not 2.

Comment: @Zloj ok. fixed it.